# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined core.js:24134

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on Ionic app, as a fresher and i am facing these problems in my console
and not able to identify the error so please help me with this error in the console
i will display the errors in console first
These errors are repeating for many projects so please help me fix this error
since i am not able to get any browser output
My vscode also doesn't show any error

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined  core.js:24134

    at registerNgModuleType (core.js:24134)
    at core.js:24145
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at registerNgModuleType (core.js:24145)
    at new NgModuleFactory$1 (core.js:24242)
    at compileNgModuleFactory__POST_R3__ (core.js:27786)
    at PlatformRef.bootstrapModule (core.js:28024)
    at Module../src/main.ts (main.ts:11)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)
    at Object.0 (main.ts:12)


HTML CODE:i did my coding here, if there is anything i need to change in my coding [please mention that also]
```

My code i am working to create student marklist,that i need to get the marks for different students in an array so that i can create this task and add in my app for the school, another couple more tasks are similar in this way so please help me in this task which in turn will help me in other tasks also thank you.

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>marklist</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content>
 
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label placeholder="Class">Class</ion-label>
        <ion-select slot="end">
        <ion-select-option >class(1-5)</ion-select-option>
        <ion-select-option >class(6-12)</ion-select-option>
        </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
        
    <ion-item>
        <ion-button *ngIf="hell" (click)="CreateRecord()" [disabled]="false">
        <ion-icon size="small" slot="icon-only" name="add"></ion-icon>&nbsp;CreateRecord </ion-button>

        <ion-button *ngIf="!hell"(click)="CreateRecord()">
        <ion-icon size="small" slot="icon-only" name="add"></ion-icon>&nbsp;HideRecord</ion-button>
    </ion-item>

  <ng-container *ngIf="!hell">
    <ion-grid>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col style="font-size: larger;margin-left: 40px;">Sno</ion-col>
          <ion-col style="font-size: larger;margin-left: 180px;">Subject</ion-col>
          <ion-col style="font-size: larger;margin-left: 250px;" >Mark</ion-col>
       </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
    
    <ng-container *ngFor="let num of subject;let i=index">
      <ion-grid>
      <ion-row> 
        <ion-col><ion-card"><ion-input value="{{i+1}}"></ion-input></ion-card></ion-col>
        <ion-col><ion-card"><ion-input type ="text-only"></ion-input></ion-card></ion-col>
        <ion-col><ion-card"><ion-input type ="number" [(ngModel)]="v1[i]" ></ion-input></ion-card></ion-col>
      </ion-row>
      </ion-grid>
    </ng-container>

      <div>
        <ion-button (click)="addForm()" class="btn btn-success">+</ion-button>
        <ion-button (click)="subForm()" class="btn btn-danger">-</ion-button>
      </div>
      
      </ng-container>
      <ion-card>
        <ion-label>Total</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="number">{{v1[i]}}</ion-input>
      </ion-card>
</ion-content>


typescript codes:

import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { FormsModule, FormGroup, FormControl, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { Component, OnInit, NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import {MarklistService} from './marklist.service';


@Component({
 
 selector: 'app-marklist',
  
templateUrl: './marklist.page.html',
 
 styleUrls: ['./marklist.page.scss'],

})

export class MarklistPage implements OnInit {


i:any; 

v1:number[];

subject:number[];

hell:boolean = true;

n=1;index:any;


constructor() { }

  
ngOnInit() {
    
this.subject = Array(this.n).fill(0).map((x,i)=>i);


  }
  
CreateRecord(){

       this.hell=!this.hell;

  }



  addForm(){
   
 this.n++;
 
 this.subject = Array(this.n).fill(0).map((x,i)=>i);
 
 }
 
 
 subForm(){
  
 
   this.subject = Array(this.n).splice(this.index,this.n--);
 
 }

}
```

i am facing these problems sir/mam so please help me in identifying the undefined id problem
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its hard to tell by the code section that you just shared.
It seems that there is a problem with the array that you are using - I guess it the subject that you are running in the html that you have shared.

The error you got usually popping when you are trying to refer to an object property, such as "id", when the object does not exist.

I.e., the following code will throw similar error:

```
let student: Student; 
student.id = 6;
```

The right implementation will be:

```
let student: Student = {
id: 6
}
```

If you are running in loop, you can add null check for the given object.

```
if (student) {
student.id = 6;
}
```

Hope it helped.

Comment: Sir, one more request what is the best website or book to learn about ionic and typescript sir,please let me know thank you